# Is it possible to have Global Methods in C#

Tags: c#, static-libraries, static-methods

So I have a static class lets say its called Worker, and lets say
I have a method inside it called Wait(float f) and its all public so I can acess it anywhere like so:

```
Worker.Wait(1000);
```

Now what I am wondering is there any way I can define some kind of unique
special methods so I could just do it short like this:

```
Wait(1000);
```

(Without having it in the class I would use it in) ?

Comment: U can try one hack, make a C++ dll define method and call extern method without class name throughout C# project .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[With C# 6 this can be done](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx). At the top of your file you need to add a `using static Your.Type.Name.Here;`.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

    public static class Worker
    {
        public static void Wait(int msec)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}

//In another file

using static MyNamespace.Worker;

public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Wait(500); //Is the same as calling "MyNamespace.Worker.Wait(500);" here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it just feels like creating a little scripting language and that makes it warm around my heart :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot have methods that are not part of a class in C#.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well even in C# 6 they are part of the class, that's just syntax sugar (as you of course know).

Comment: @Evk Yes, I know, but the op's question was "*is there any way I can define some kind of unique special methods so I could just do it short like this: `Wait(1000);`*" and the answer to that is yes, you can call it that way in C# 6.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain well I was confused because this answer you comment states "you cannot have methods that are not part of a class", and then you respond "this can be done in C# 6" :)

Comment: I agree @ScottChamberlain's answer is the right one, my answer is an answer to a bit of a different question.

Comment: I guess I was responding to what I felt was more the spirit of the answer of: "you cannot have methods that ***look like they*** are not part of a class" instead of the literal text.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not, Methods belong to a class, if you do Wait(1) is because you are in a class where that method is defined (or is the parent class)

## Edit...

As commented that was true up to C# 5, this can be done in C# 6 now it can be done importing statically some classes...

take a look at **Scott Chamberlain"s** [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40515300/982161) and link to MSDN

Comment: thanks @ScottChamberlain, thanks for the comment... i will make a correction as soon as I find that on the MSDN and I will for sure give you the credits on that...